# External usb device not seen by deja-dup

Tags: usb, mount, backup, deja-dup

I have an issue with an external USB backup device (ext4) that has been declared in the FSTAB, and is mounted ok. I get the message 'waiting for Music Backup to be connected' when I try and use deja-dup to create a new backup. Where does it get that name (Music Backup) from? If I know where, maybe I can change it? The USB is empty. The only other thing to mention is that I did manage to create a backup a long time ago which was called Music Backup, but now I cannot view the details under the 'overview' option.